# Powers not visible on hero?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

In the "Introduction Mission" of the Dwarf armies "Thorgrim Grudgebearer" has abilities if you select him in battle, they're around his portrait. However in later missions there are no abilities around his portrait. Is this because he's been leveled down past the tutorial? Or have I hidden them somehow?

[image: shows now powers when thorgrim selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this in my vampire campaign as well.

You will be able to unlock them relative early with your two or three skill points.

I think they unlock the ability for your usage to help you to learn how to use them in-battle.

Edit: Vampire Count let you use the first tier skill. Didn't realize there were other skills that aren't first tier.

Comment: on further inspection it doesn't appear to be the first skill point, it's actually after the 2nd "tier" of skill points, at least for the dwarves.